# An equivalence between function $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Recently on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160138/algebra-problem-that-you-have-to-assume-certain-criteria-at-the-end/3160204?noredirect=1) answer to  one of my questions user farruhota replied that

> Alternatively, note the [property of inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Inverses_and_composition): 
>   $$f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$
>   Hence:
>   $$f(f(x))=x \iff f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$$

How is $f(f(x))=x \iff f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ derived from the equation $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$?

Is this "$f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$" thing only valid when the function is $f(f(x))=x$?

Thanks,
Max0815

Comment: For the second question, it is a direct consequence of the definition of inverse function. Recall that $g : Y \to X$ is called an inverse function of $f : X \to Y$ if $$g(f(x)) = x \text{ for all } x \in X, \qquad f(g(y)) = y \text{ for all } y \in Y.$$ Now the property in the second question is simply the case when $X = Y$ so that $f : X \to Y$ and its inverse $f^{-1} : X \to X$ live on the same set.

Comment: @SangchulLee so yes, it is only valid in that case?

Comment: The second property holds whenever a function $f : X \to X$ has an inverse. It need not be an involution (i.e. $f(f(x)) = x$) to satisfy the property, although any involution will certainly do.

Comment: Note that the domain and codomain must be *equal* (and f invertible) in order for $f(f^-1(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))$ to even make sense. That each is $x$ also holds, but still only when domain same as codomain.

Comment: @SangchulLee so you mean that if $f(x)$ has an inverse and satisfies that $f(f(x))=x$, then $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is true?

Comment: Let me summarize two claims. (1) If $f : X \to X$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$, then $f(f^{-1}(x)) = f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in X$, which is simply the definition of inverse function specialized to this very case. (2) If $f : X \to X$ satisfies $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in X$, then $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$ (which we did not assume at the beginning) and in fact, $f^{-1} = f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f: X \to X$ has an inverse $f^{-1}: X \to X$ (in particular, $f$ is a bijection)

If $f(f(x)) = x$, apply $f^{-1}$ to get $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.

If $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ apply $f$ to get $f(f(x)) = x$. Very simple.

Comment: A question on your notation in the first sentence. You mean that this is only true when $f(x)=x$?

Comment: @Max0815 no, we only assumed $f$ is a function from $X$ to $X$ with an inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So to generalize, I have

> Suppose $f: X \to X$ has an inverse $f^{-1}: X \to X$ (in particular,
>   $f$ is a bijection)
>
> If $f(f(x)) = x$, apply $f^{-1}$ to get $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.
>
> If $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ apply $f$ to get $f(f(x)) = x$. Very simple.
>
> > user [Mariah](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/319890/mariah)

as the answer to my first question.

For my second question,

> If $f:X\rightarrow X$ satisfies $f(f(x))=x$ for all  $x\in X$, then
>   $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$ and in fact, $f^{-1}=f$
>
> > user [SangChul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee)

This relation $f^{-1}=f$ is valid when functions are involutions, when a function $f:X\rightarrow X$ maps a number $x$ to $y$, and another application of the same function maps $y$ to $x$. However,

> this property holds whenever a function $f:X\rightarrow X$ has an inverse.
>
> > user [SangChul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee)

Also,

> Note that the domain and codomain must be *equal* (and $f$ invertible) in order for $f(f^{−1}(x))=f^{−1}(f(x))$
>   to even make sense. That each is $x$ also holds, but still only when domain same as codomain.
>
> > user [coffeemath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/483139/coffeemath)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you still seem to think that if $f$ has an inverse then it is an involution - this is wrong.

Comment: @Mariah no I think that if f has inverse and has an involution, then the property f=f-1 is definitely true